# avoid zero error when calculating with numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, divide-by-zero

I have 3 numpy arrays like this:

```
a1=[1,1,1]
a2=[1,2,3]
a3=[1,1,1]
```

I want to create a new array by calculting with the other 3:

```
    a4 = np.arctan(a3/(a1-a2))/2
```

Now ofc when a1=a2, a zero error appears. Is there a way to avoid this?

When using lists instead of arrays I can avoid the error by using for loops and if statements. But this is no solution because I have a lot of data and it takes forever to calculate.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When delta X is 0, the arctan is undefined.  What do you want the answer to be?  Infinity?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [np.arctan2](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html), which takes the change in y and change in x as separate arguments.

```
a4 = np.arctan2(a3, a1 - a2) / 2
```